# PLT.PSD unable to match plt.psd vs actual output data

Tags: python, matplotlib, signals, signal-processing

I am actually trying the PSD of a signal using the plt.psd function.

```
Pxxf, psd_frequencies = plt.psd(phase,Fs=50,scale_by_freq= False,noverlap=250,NFFT=500,label = "3 minute",return_line=False)
```

Where phase is the input signal.

This is what it outputs:
[image: This is what it outputs]

but if I am to plot it using the output values it does not really work. Here is what I do.

```
Pxxf, psd_frequencies = plt.psd(phase,Fs=50,scale_by_freq= False,noverlap=250,NFFT=500,label = "3 minute",return_line=False)

plt.cla()
plt.plot(psd_frequencies,Pxxf)
```

This is what I get:
[image: This is what I get]

Any thoughts on why there is such a difference?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [matplotlib.pyplot.psd`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.psd.html)'s documentation,

> For plotting, the power is plotted as 10log10(Pxx) for decibels, though Pxx itself is returned.

So, to get a similar result while manually plotting the returned arrays, try

```
plt.plot(psd_frequencies,10*np.log10(Pxxf))
```